# non-chunked multipart/mixed POST?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send multiple binary files to a web service in a single multipart/mixed POST but can't seem to get it to work... target server rejects it.  One thing I noticed is Node is trying to do the encoding as chunked, which I don't want:

```
POST /SomeFiles HTTP/1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=123456789012345
Host: host.server.com
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

*How do I get it to stop being chunked?*  Docs say that can be disabled by setting the Content-Length in the main request header but I can't set the Content-Length since, among other reasons, I'm loading one file at a time -- but it shouldn't be required either since it's multipart.

I **think** the rest is OK (excepting it's not chunked, unless the `req_post.write()` is doing that part), e.g. for the initial part I:

```
    var req_post = https.request({
        hostname: 'host.server.com',
        path: '/ManyFiles',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'MIME-Version': '1.0',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=' + boundary
        }
    },...);
```

and then pseudo-code:

```
while ( true ) {
    // { get next file here }
    req_post.write('\r\n--' + boundary + '\r\nContent-Type: ' + filetype + '\r\nContent-Length: ' + filesize + '\r\n\r\n');
    req_post.write(chunk);// filesize
    if ( end ) {
        req_post.write('\r\n--' + boundary + '--\r\n');
        req_post.end();
        break;
    }
}
```

Any help/pointers is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is you cannot disable chunked without setting content-length.  The chunked encoding was introduced for cases where you do not know the size of the payload when you start transmitting.  Originally, content-length was required and the recipient knew it had the full message when it received content-length bytes.  Chunked encoding removed that requirement by transmitting mini-payloads each with a content-length, followed by a zero-size to denote completion of the payload.  So, if you do not set the content-length, and you do not use the chunked methodology, the recipient will never know when it has the full payload.

To help solve your problem, if you cannot send chunked and do not want to read all the files before sending, take a look at [fs.stat](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback).  You can use it to get the file size without reading the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm including the Content-Length in each MIME part, but even without that, the MIME boundary signals the end of the message - that is, the HTTP protocol handles this case OK.  This seems like a limitation of Node and not HTTP...

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but it needs to know when the entire response is received (i.e. how many MIME parts are being sent).  This wiki has a pretty good explanation.  I suggest reading through at least the first part.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding.  Ultimately, if you do not want chunked encoding, you have to compute and set the content-length on the entire request body, not just each part.