# Issue sending complete multipart/mixed request via node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to POST a multipart/mixed request which does NOT use chunking. From what I've read this means I have to essentially roll the request off of **http** instead of using npm **request**.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144349/non-chunked-multipart-mixed-post) got me started, but I'm stuck.

The first part of the request is a basic XML payload which describes a file. The second part is the file which is to be "published".

When I call request.end() I see that the POST hits the server it's intended for. However, the response callback doesn't get hit for 15-20 seconds. When it does, I see the following:

**The client failed to send a complete request before the timeout period elapsed.**

Perhaps I am calculating the content-length incorrectly so the Server is waiting on me?

```
   //Calc size of string in XMLWriter object
    var xmlRequestSize = Buffer.byteLength(dsXml.toString());

    //Calculate Content-Size for each of two parts of a multi-part request
    data = fs.readFileSync("Blood Testing.tde")
    var fileRequestSize = Buffer.byteLength(data.toString());

    console.log(xmlRequestSize);
    console.log(fileRequestSize);  

    //Multi-part boundary
    var boundary = 'zxyzzy123456boundary';

    //Request options
    var postOptions=
        {
            hostname: tableauServer,
            port: 8888, // for proxy
            path: '/api/2.0/sites/' + siteID + '/datasources?overwrite=true',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-Tableau-Auth': adminAuthToken, 
                'Content-Length': xmlRequestSize + fileRequestSize,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=' + boundary

            }
        }


   postCallback = function(response) {
       console.log("Hit callback");
       var str = '';
      //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`

      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
      });

      //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
      response.on('end', function () {
        console.log(str);

      });
    }

    var req_post = http.request(postOptions, postCallback);

    //Part 1 metadata
     req_post.write("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition: name='request_payload'\r\nContent-Type: 'text/xml'\r\n\r\n");

     //Part 1 Body
     req_post.write(dsXml.toString());

    //Part 2 metadata
     req_post.write("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nname='tableau_datasource'; filename='Blood Testing.tde'\r\nContent-Type: 'application/octet-stream'\r\n\r\n");

    //Part 2 Body
     req_post.write(fs.createReadStream('Blood Testing.tde').toString());


    //Close Boundary
     req_post.write("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

     console.log("About to .end()");               
     req_post.end();

    // callback(null);   

    }
```

Any assistance on how to calculate this puppy and/or anything else I've done wrong would be appreciated.

...and after breaking out Fiddler, it looks like none of the stuff I want to add via request.write are making it INTO the request. Fiddler complains:

[image]

...and if I look at the raw request, there is nothing there but the header. Odd. Ideas?

**Edit #2: Final Solution**

```
// Simple upload of a TDE file < 64MB inline in the request.
var simplePublish = function(callback) {
        //Site ID of your 'REST' site. Lookup with REST API or PGAdmin3                       
        var siteID = '98823511-cfc3-4e24-9790-27e1855fed75';

        //First, build the XML for the POST
        var dsXml = new XMLWriter();
        dsXml.startElement('tsRequest')
                    .startElement('datasource')
                    .writeAttribute('name', 'BloodTesting')
                        .startElement('project')
                            // ID of the Default Project in REST site. Lookup with REST API or PGAdmin3
                            .writeAttribute('id', 'a8a1c0c6-0e49-4243-a271-d49f79c7ccdb')
                        .endElement()
                    .endElement()
                .endElement();
        console.log(dsXml.toString());

    var CRLF = '\r\n';
    var form = new FormData();


    form.append('request_payload', dsXml.toString(), {contentType: 'text/xml'});
    form.append('tableau_datasource', fs.createReadStream('Blood Testing.tde'),{contentType: 'application/octet-stream'});

    form.submit(
        {
            host: tableauServer,
            //port: 8888, // for proxy
            path: '/api/2.0/sites/' + siteID + '/datasources?overwrite=true',
            //method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-Tableau-Auth': adminAuthToken, 
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=' + form.getBoundary()
            }
        }, function(err, res) {
              if (err) throw err;
             console.log(res.statusCode);
             var str = '';
              //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`

              res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                str += chunk;
              });

              //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
              res.on('end', function () {
                console.log(str);

              });

        });
```

Comment: Your calculated `Content-Length` only consists of the `xmlRequestSize` plus `fileRequestSize` – what about other parts of the request body, such as the actual boundaries, and the additional meta data (`Content-Disposition`, `Content-Type`, `name`, `filename`) …?

Comment: If I was missing stuff like that, wouldn't my indicated content-length be too low? I'd actually send MORE stuff to the server than I told it to expect, so I'd get a different error message. Interestingly enough, if I purposefully lower the value, vs. calculate it, this is what happens.

Comment: Have you tried using a module like [`form-data`](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data) instead of trying to do the multipart formatting manually?

Comment: @mscdex Good call. I wasn't sure if a form library would work for this, but form-data had everything I needed. Adding final solution code in case anyone can use it...